# /articles api filtering on tag does not return any results

Tags: bug, status-planned, stack-overflow-for-teams, api-v2.3

I am attempting to pull the articles from my company's collective. They are all returned when no `tagged` filter is used.

This should return results for the articles tagged `wso2` or is there a different parameter that should be used?

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/articles?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=wso2&site=stackoverflow`

[Documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/articles)

Comment: This is indeed a bug, where filtering the `/articles` API using tags on stackoverflow.com will result in an empty data set.